# OpenGL rendering several mesh instances

Tags: opengl

I started learning OpenGL, now I'm going to try to develop something on my own and got stuck on a doubt.

I'm going to render models that have about 50k primitives (cylinders, cubes, cones, etc). Less than 1/4 of them are 'unique', I mean, have the same dimensions, but different positioning and rotation. So I thought that somehow I could fill a data buffer with only basic vertices and then draw them with individual transformations matrices.

From what I've read, I should use a buffer for vertices and a buffer for indices, so I don't waste memory storing repeated vertices.

All of them are stored in a single big buffer (that's because I read that this is more efficient if the one single buffer if it do not exceed a 1~3mb limit).

To draw them I'm trying to use glDrawElements, but since they are all in a single buffer, I cannot update the individual matrices to update the shaders so they can draw each mesh in the correct position.

One solution would be to use thousands of small buffers and then update the matrices between the glDrawElements calls.

Another would be discard the indices buffer and store only the vertices so I can draw them using glDrawArrays, which allows me to draw only a small part of the buffer.

Anything I said above is wrong? Which option would result in better performance? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you want [instancing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). You can pass the per-instance transformation matrix (as well as any other per-instance data) in various ways, see the link.

Comment: @peppe Thank you, that's exactly what I need. Going to study about it before start coding. If you wish post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Instancing could certainly be useful in this case. But some clarification on the basics in your post. Just because you have everything in one buffer does not mean that you **have to** draw it all in a single draw call. The last argument of `glDrawElements()` is an offset. So you can draw part of the indices, change state, draw another part, etc., while still having all the indices and vertices in a single buffer.